# Can I have more than one custom URL Scheme for authentication with the Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, configuration

upon reading the docs it states:

> Adding your Facebook App ID
>
> Finally, you need to place the Facebook app ID in two places in your
>   application's main .plist file. Create a key called FacebookAppID with
>   a string value, and add the app ID there:
>
> Also, create an array key called URL types with a single array
>   sub-item called URL Schemes. Give this a single item with your app ID
>   prefixed with fb:

My question is the following.  We have 2 development environments with our app, and I would like to avoid creating another build target, when there are basically a couple of environment variables that need to change.  The docs here above status 'a single item', but it would be great if I could put in 2 items, i.e.  fb8234923847293 and fb0238343466  (not the real ids)

I don't think this will work.

Is there anyway I can declare multiple URL schemes, so that if the facebook app wants to launch my app after authenticating, my app will respond to requests from either of those 2 development facebook apps that we have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, my question was based on something I must have remembered incorrectly, because I thought the app doesn't deal well with multiple Facebook App URLs.  It does.

For completeness, I'll answer the question.  In the FB docs where it tells you to create an item in the URL Schemes array, you can just keep adding more schemes based on the various FB App IDs in that array, and the app will respond to any one of those.

Simple.

Comment: I am running into a similar situation. We have 3 app environments (development, staging, production) and have a separate Facebook application for each environment. Using the new Facebook SDK (3.15), we are required to specify a URL Scheme, FacebookAppID, and FacebookDisplayName. I see how it would be easy to have multiple URL Schemes, but the other two are more difficult. Were you able to solve that problem?